# Why does get_capture_delay include rsmp_delay,

Tags: android, audio, audiorecord, hal, aec

guys.
    I am studying AEC for android and more specificly,I am studying HAL for tuna project.
code:
[audio_hw.c](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/device/samsung/tuna/audio/audio_hw.c)

```
static void get_capture_delay(struct tuna_stream_in *in,
                   size_t frames,
                   struct echo_reference_buffer *buffer)
...
    delay_ns = kernel_delay + buf_delay + rsmp_delay;
...
```

I found get_capture_delay includes rsmp_delay.I do not think it is true.
I believe there is not any relation between rsmp_delay and delay_ns .
Because delay_ns is calculated by buffered audio capture data(both in Linux kernel and HAL buffer) and sampling rate.

Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I do not think it is true"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Here they are calculating over all delay.delay that will take for re-sample too.But later they will subtract re-sample delay from delay_ns.if you see mEchoReference->read() function,you will get clarity.

Comment: But later they will subtract re-sample delay from delay_ns ------------>Thanks for your help. Now I think i understood why they add rsmp_delay. But why will they subtract re-sample delay from delay_ns.